# solve by induction

Tags: induction

$$\sum_{r=2}^n{1\over r^2-1}=\frac34-{2n+1\over 2n(n+1)}$$

*after I got to* $n=k+1$ *and tried to get both sides equal I got stuck,*

*prove*: ***$n=k+1$*** ;

$${1\over k^2 -1} + {1\over (k+1)^2 -1}=\frac34 - {2(k+1) +1\over 2(k+1)(k+2)}$$

**any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: The sum is [telescopic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series): $$\frac1{r^2-1}=\frac1{(r-1)(r+1)}=\frac12\bigg(\frac1{r-1}-\frac1{r+1}\bigg)$$

Comment: Using the telescopic series suggested by @Lucian, all terms cancel out except $\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{n}, -\frac{1}{n+1}$. And you will get the same result.

Comment: Check this for $n=2$ and you will find out that it is not correct: $\frac{1}{3}\neq\frac{3}{4}-\frac{2\times2-1}{2\times2\times\left(2+1\right)}$

Comment: my bad its 2k+1

Comment: The base case will be true if $\frac{3}{4}$ is replaced by $\frac{7}{12}$.

Comment: its ${2k+1}$ not ${2k-1}$ sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle\sum_{r=2}^n{1\over r^2-1}=\frac34-{2n-1\over 2n(n+1)}$ holds true for $n=m$

Let $\implies\displaystyle\sum_{r=2}^m{1\over r^2-1}=\frac34-{2m-1\over 2m(m+1)}$

For $n=m+1,$
$\displaystyle\implies\sum_{r=2}^{m+1}{1\over r^2-1}=\sum_{r=2}^m{1\over r^2-1}+\frac1{(m+1)^2-1}=\frac34-{2m-1\over 2m(m+1)}+\frac1{m(m+2)}$

Now, $\displaystyle\frac1{m(m+2)}-\frac{2m-1}{2m(m+1)}=\frac{2(m+1)-(m+2)(2m-1)}{2m(m+2)(m+1)}=\frac{-m(2m+1)}{2m(m+2)(m+1)}$
$\displaystyle=-\frac{2m+1}{2(m+2)(m+1)}$

Now establish the base case i.e., for $n=1$

Comment: i did all that already :/ still couldn't get it, algebra is lagging atm

Comment: @luke, have you got your answer?

Comment: your numinator in ur answe is not like mine, i got $2(m+1)+1$

Comment: @luke, have you identified any mistake with the calculation of mine or yours

Comment: you seem to have taken the 2's away instead of adding them maybe?

Comment: i've gotten it, thanks. you just mistaked the 2's.

Comment: Base case is not $n=1$ but $n=2$ and if I am not mistaken then the base case fails to be true.

Comment: i've worked the base case to be true -> $\frac13$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{r=2}^{n+1}\frac{1}{r^{2}-1}=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{2n-1}{2n\left(n+1\right)}+\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)^{2}-1}=\frac{3}{4}-\left[\frac{2n-1}{2n\left(n+1\right)}-\frac{1}{n\left(n+2\right)}\right]=$$$$\frac{3}{4}-\frac{2n+1}{2\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)}$$